# How to split a string based on ":" in MS-Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My excel column is filled with words like this:

```
1.) ABC:DCF
2.) DCF:FED
```

I want to split each word based on **" : "** and put the result in adjacent columns such that "ABC:DCF" in cell "A:1" becomes "ABC" in cell "B:1" and "DCF" in cell "C:1" and also corresponding values in each column. How to do this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Go to Data tab, then Text to Columns option. Later, choose "Delimited" option and then select "other" and put any delimiter you want.

Answer (score 87):

Text to columns will work. Another option, if you want to keep the original value, is to use formulas:
 
in B1

```
=left(a1,find(":",a1)-1)
```

in C1

```
=mid(a1,find(":",a1)+1,len(a1))
```

Comment: The original value can be kept even with the other solution (you can specify a different column to store the new values), but I like this solution better because it allows to always have up-to-date values (i.e. if you modify A1, B1 and C1 will update, while the text-to-column option does not).

Comment: This is a brilliant solution

Answer (score 26):

If you can use VBA then you can make use of the `Split()` function. Here's a User-Defined Function (UDF) that you can use in a cell. It splits on your choice of character and returns the *n*th element of the split list.

See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/354511)
for information on how to define a UDF.

```
Function STR_SPLIT(str, sep, n) As String
    Dim V() As String
    V = Split(str, sep)
    STR_SPLIT = V(n - 1)
End Function
```

So you'd need to enter:

```
=STR_SPLIT(A1, ":", 1) // for the first half
=STR_SPLIT(A1, ":", 2) // for the second half
```

Comment: Very Nice, didnt know it was so easy to create your own formulas

Comment: This is perfect for splitting a URL into its component parts.

Answer (score 9):

Paste it to B1 and fill it to columns on right and rows down:

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,":",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))`

*Edit: I previously posted localized version of the formula, where ',' was replaced with ';'. That doesn't work in US-version of Excel:*

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1;":";REPT(" ";999));COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998;999))`

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Could you add a few sentences to your answer to explain what this does and how it works?  That will enhance its educational value.  Thanks.

Comment: Yea, sure. It does the same thing what Text to Columns from Data tab does, except it does't it with formula. You could replace the ":" by a different Delimiter or refer to a delimiter from the other cell.

Comment: Excel says that this is not a valid formula when you paste it into a cell. Please check and update.

Comment: Hi thilina R! Thank you for notifying. I made the adjustment for the US-version of Excel. Please let me know if you have any trouble with that now or if anything is unclear.

Comment: Very nice. The only answer so far that allows you to deal with as many delimiters as you may want, without creating your own function.

Comment: Great! Very elegant solution - unlimited columns, only limitation is the size per String of 998.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an array formula to do this.

If you have ABC:DEF:GHI in cell A1 then if you enter the following formula in B1:D1 it will split out the text in A1 by the colon character.

=IFERROR(MID(":"&$A1&":",SMALL(IF(MID(":"&$A1&":",ROW($1:$999),1)=":",ROW($1:$999),""),COLUMN()-1)+1,SMALL(IF(MID(":"&$A1&":",ROW($1:$999),1)=":",ROW($1:$999),""),(COLUMN()))-SMALL(IF(MID(":"&$A1&":",ROW($1:$999),1)=":",ROW($1:$999),""),COLUMN()-1)-1),"")

You need to hit CTRL+ENTER to enter the formula.
The main part that is repeated 3 times is this bit... 
IF(MID(":"&$A1&":",ROW($1:$999),1)=":",ROW($1:$999),"") 
which gets an array of the positions of the colon (using the rows 1 to 999 although you could use more). This returns the array

1;"";"";"";5;"";"";"";9;"";"";"";13;"";"";""

Using the SMALL function you get the 1st and second smallest values which gives you 1 and 5. Then it uses the MID function to get the string between the first and 5th characters (bearing in mind the string is ":ABC:DEF:FHI:" because we added the separator to the beginning and end). Then in the next column you get the text between the 5th and 9th characters etc.